# parse.initialize error for parse.com

Tags: java, android, oncreate, parse-platform

This should be an easy fix. But I am a new programmer. I can't find answers anywhere. I just started building my app, (For the second time. My computer was stolen so lost all my previous work.) I am using Pasre.com. Haven't written any code yet, only the `parse.initialize`. I am already getting an error on this line

```
public void onCreate() {
          Parse.initialize(this, "xxxx", "xxxxx"); 
        }
```

My error states this

`Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
 construct(s)
- Syntax error on token "void", @ expected`

Like I said, I am rebuilding an app that I have started before, and I didn't have this issue then. But this is the newest version of eclipse, and I haven't programmed anything with it yet. (Hoping everything is installed properly) I am running Linux, not sure if that would matter either. I am a new programmer, so if an explanation is needed, please be thorough. Thanks for looking guys.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was an easy answer. I imported the parse-1.2.2 javadoc. But that's not all you need to do.I guess you should download their [blank project](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#android/blank) and import it. Build the app off that.